# Laravel framework - vendor folder error

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

There is no vendor folder in laravel project. I download the laravel using composer create-project laravel/laravel. What problem?

Comment: run composer install on your project directory

Comment: What is the composer install command line

Comment: This command install all the dependencies in your composer.json file of your project which are located at your vendor folder

Comment: Try this command line using project directory `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel folder_name`

Answer (score 0):

Please delete your current laravel project and install new one. It might be a problem when downloading laravel project.

You can use alternate way instead of using composer. You can download laravel from github.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some issues here. Have you ran `composer global require "laravel/installer"` before? And have you given a name, for example `composer create-project laravel/laravel my_project`?

The project (`cd my_project`) will be created in the folder where you run it. If the outcome is still not the way you expected, try `composer clear-cache` followed by `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my_project` so you bypass the cached packages.